# Don't see Airplay Icon on my Macbook Pro Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, airplay

Is there a Freeware AirParrot Alternative? I don't want to burn my wallet to the ground as it is. I've tried ServeMeTo with StreamMeTo freeware but didn't get better results.

Comment: The title and body don't seem to match…?

Comment: The fact is my MacBook Pro model is mid 2007 running mountain lion, just recently purchased AppleTV at Target store and i want freeware/Shareware alternatives besides AirParrot, ServeMeTo, StreamMeTo but have the same effect as airplay. I don't want to burn my wallet as it is already.

Comment: I'm not clear on why AirParrot is not working for you -? Have you contacted the developer?

Comment: It does work for me but every time i use Airparrot it keeps asking me to purchase the software when i don't have enough funds to cover the whole thing until next year.

Answer (score 1):

Mavericks is a free OS upgrade and includes the Mac to Apple TV screen mirroring that AirParrot gave to older OS X versions.

The downside is if you have other apps that are incompatible with 10.9 you'll have to choose between the airplay mirroring and the other apps. I don't know of other free options that would let you stay on 10.8 and have similar functionality.